# Packages does not exist when trying to compile with Spring

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, dependency-injection

I'm using Spring for the first time.

I setup Spring on a project on a Mac, everything dependency wise worked there without a problem, I could compile, all checked.

I've tried the same on a Windows machine, but now I get the message that the all the packages imported from the Spring Framework don't exist. Since Spring is part of the IntelliJ Ultimate, I'm struggling to find why. I've been hours trying to find the reasons, and all the answers I found don't seem connected to the same problem at all.

The only thing I can think of is that it can't find the modules, but since they are related to IntelliJ, I'm not sure how it wouldn't find it?

This is the stack trace, to be more precise:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

These messages are coming from the Java compiler. They indicate that the the classes you are attempting to import are not available on the classpath.

I do not use IntelliJ, so I do not know how to configure this properly for IntelliJ. I suspect your assertion that the Spring classes as “related to IntelliJ” is incorrect. The way this works with other tools is that, you have Spring related Jars, and then you tell the tool where to find them. In the case of using Maven or Gradle, you declare Spring as a project dependency and they fetch the jars and build things for you. In the case of other IDEs like Eclipse, you can configure a build path for your project, which typically involves pointing out exactly where the Jar files are on your disk.

Comment: It's in the IntelliJ documentation about the Ultimate version that the Spring Framework is part of the build. But checking out the building path makes sense, I just don't know how to go about it in this case and the myriad of answers I found have been of zero help in that regard.

Answer (score 0):

You could check if Spring libraries are correctly used and referenced in the build path of the project.

Comment: How does one do that?

Comment: This might help you https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/spring-support.html Please read the support documentation.

Comment: That's exactly the path I followed that drove me here.